# How to use timer.performWithDelay with a method call

Tags: class, methods, lua, coronasdk

I'm using a Lua class to create two objects, each of which must check where the other is to determine their movement. I'm attempting to use timer.performWithDelay to have them check every second, but for some reason when I try to do this, the line

```
o.moveCheckTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, o:moveCheck, 0)
```

in the class constructor throws an error stating that "Function arguments are expected near ','".

I have attempted to use an anonymous function like this:

```
o.moveCheckTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, function() o:moveCheck() end, 0)
```

but that causes the timer of both objects to only call the function for the most recent object that was created and not for itself (also very confusing behavior, and if anyone knows why this happens I would love to learn why).

I have dug through the API and info on method calls thoroughly, but I can't seem to find anything that uses them both together, and I feel like I'm missing something.

How can I use the method call as the listener for this timer?

Here is the full constructor:

```
Melee = {}
Melee.__index = Melee

function Melee:new(id, name, lane, side)
    local o = {}
    setmetatable(o, Melee)
    o.id = id
    o.name = name
    o.lane = lane
    o.side = side
    if name == "spearman" then
        o.maxhp = 100
        o.range = 1
        o.damage = {10, 20}
        o.imageName = "images/rebels/spearman.png"
    else
        error("Attempted to create melee unit with undefined name")
    end
    o.hp = o.maxhp
    --Display self
    o.image = display.newImageRect(mainGroup, "images/rebels/spearman.png", 80, 80)
    o.image.x = 0
    o.image.y = lanes[lane]
    o.image.anchorY = 1
    if side == 2 then
        o.image.xScale = -1
        o.image:setFillColor(0.8)
        o.image.x = display.contentWidth - 100
    end
    --Move and attack
    local destination = display.contentWidth
    if side == 2 then
        destination = 0
    end
    o.moving = 1
    o.movement = transition.to(o.image, {x = destination, time = 30000+math.random(-200,200)})
    o.moveCheckTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, o:moveCheck, 0)
    --o.attackTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, self:attack, 0)
    return o
end
```

Comment: Your first attempt didn't work just because that syntax isn't a thing in Lua, and there's not much more to it than that. Your second attempt not working is a really good question, though. I'd advise you to edit the question to only include it.

Comment: the colon operator `:` only comes with the call operator `()`. please provide the code where you create the two objects and the implemtation of `moveCheck`